# How to bind dataGridView with my own object array?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview, datasource

I have a class:

```
  public class MarketTrade
  {
        public int trade_seq;
        public double amount;
        public double price;
        public direction dir; //=enum
  }
```

I want my dataGridView1 show table like:

```
trade_seq   amount  price   dir
00001       10      100     buy
00002       5       99      buy
00003       5       100     buy
00004       15      98      sell
00005       20      100     sell
```

I try this but failed:

```
  MarketTrade[] trades =  GetTrades();
  this.dataGridView1.DataSource = trades;
```

Is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: Turn those fields into properties.

Comment: Databinding works with *properties*.  Your `MarketTrade` class just has public members/fields.  Also, price and amount would probably make more sense as `decimal`

Comment: OK, properties works fine, thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class with properties as follows:

```
public class MarketTrade
{
    public int TradeSeq { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public Direction Dir { get; set; }

}
```

Create an enum as follows:

```
public enum Direction
{
    Buy,
    Sell
}
```

Create your data source (I have created a random Data Source with the help of this method for 10 objects):

```
private MarketTrade[] GetTrades()
    {
        MarketTrade[] arrMarketTrades = new MarketTrade[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            arrMarketTrades[i] = new MarketTrade()
            {
                Amount = (i + 1) * 4,
                Dir = i / 2 == 0 ? Direction.Buy : Direction.Sell,
                Price = (i + 1) * 2,
                TradeSeq = i
            };
        }

        return arrMarketTrades;
    }
```

Finally, setting the data source in form load event, you can change it as per your needs:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = this.GetTrades();
    }
```